# Using Get-RetentionPolicy on a mailbox with [No Policy]

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I would like to apply our default mailbox retention policy to all mailboxes without a policy.

When running Get-Mailbox and filtering by `Name` and `Retentionpolicy` I can see the users who have no retention policy because the `Retentionpolicy` field is blank. For the users with the blank retention policy field in Exchange, their policy in the Exchange online panel shows up as [No Policy].

I've attempted using `$CurrentPolicy=(Get-RetentionPolicy "POLICY").distinguishedName` and for  POLICY I've tried `$null`, `false`, `[No Policy]`, and an empty string. Those attempts resulted in an error about those policies not existing.

Ideally I'd like to be able to sort by that [No Policy] value, and use `Get-Mailbox -Filter "RetentionPolicy -ne '$BlankPolicy'" -Resultsize unlimited` and pipe that into a `Set-Mailbox`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if RetentionPolicy is filterable.  However you can probably post-filter with a `Where{}` clause.  I know in on-prem the value would be null, so something like:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | 
Where-Object{ !$_.RetentionPolicy }
```

This should return all mailboxes that aren't assigned a retention policy.

Note: So far as I know the cmdlet `Get-RetentionPolicy` cannot reflect which mailboxes are assigned a given policy. Just to resolve some confusion in how the question was asked.